# Taskbar is hidden when WPF window is maximized (changing taskbar position)

Tags: wpf

when the application is maximized the taskbar is hidden from the user. I tried solution below:

```
 Width = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width; 
 Height = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height; 
 Left = 0; 
 Top = 0;
```

But the solution wont fix the issue if user transfers the taskbar to the side while application is already open.

I tried setting WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow", and it works. However, my problem now is there is a tilte bar, i need to find a way to remove the title bar.

Comment: Set `WindowStyle="None"`

Comment: @mitya when i set windowstyle to none, th taskbar is covered when maximized.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the combination of following two lines?

```
    WindowState="Maximized"
    WindowStyle="None"
```

Comment: Use this =>                                                                                   `this.Width = SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenWidth;
            this.Height=SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenHeight;`